# Deploying Symfony3 app on localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, routes

I'm trying to deploy my Symfony3 app (production) on my local server (Wamp) but I'm getting an error when I try to access my website through the url (http://localhost/MekriaFR/):

> No route found for "GET /MekriaFR/

Though I've my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

my config/routing.yml

```
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"

mekria_site:
    resource: "@MekriaSiteBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation
```

web/app.php

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

Does someone know where is the problem from?

Comment: No need for rewrite (Symfony .htaccess should do that), just [follow the manual](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html), make sure to set the proper `DocumentRoot` etc

Answer (score 0):

The fact it says No route found for "GET /MekriaFR/ suggests that your site's base url is just `http://localhost`, so try that first.

Do you have multiple sites set up on your machine? If so, try using apache virtualhosts file to give each site a specific url, like `http://dev.mysite.com`, and set the correct DocumentRoot. In your OS hosts file, add 127.0.0.1 `http://dev.mysite.com`

Of course the last thing to check is the Routes you have configured! Is `/MekriaFR` in there?